# Colouring points based on cluster on matplotlib

Tags: python, visualization

I have a set of points where I performed a KMeans classification. How make a plot where the color of the point is based on the cluster they belong?

EDIT: for clarification, having the set of points, I want to use the values of the array generated from `KMeans.predict()` ( from sklearn) to choose the color of each point.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28232401/4993513) might also help you if you want to plot in matplotlib. Else, @Emre's answer should be good to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html) shows you how:

```
colors = np.array([x for x in 'bgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmykbgrcmyk'])
colors = np.hstack([colors] * 20)
...
if hasattr(algorithm, 'cluster_centers_'):
        centers = algorithm.cluster_centers_
        center_colors = colors[:len(centers)]
        plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], s=100, c=center_colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me if you know an answer for this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26310/clustering-using-k-means-in-sklearn-in-python